# Python, Yaml config file, Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stubresolver'

Tags: python, yaml

I'm trying to run a code in my raspberry PI 4B that I found in [Github](https://github.com/zentec/emul-gs232). However, I'm struggling to understand how to run it. The code works with a YAML file as config. My guess is that the `test.yaml` file can't find the module in the directory.

To run the code in the terminal I put:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi:~/Dokumente/emul-gs232-main $ python emul-gs232.py -c "/home/pi/Dokumente/emul-gs232-main/config/test.yaml"
```

What I understand is that the `emul-gs232.py` calls `test.yaml` in the section:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

The `test.yaml` file tries to call the module `stubresolver` (but it doesn't).

The module is in
`/home/pi/Dokumente/emul-gs232-main/resolvers/stubresolver.py` (it contains a class named `StubResolver`).

I created an `__init__.py` for the `stubresolver.py` in the same folder as well.

The error looks like this:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi:~/Dokumente/emul-gs232-main $ python emul-gs232.py -c 
"/home/pi/Dokumente/emul-gs232-main/config/test.yaml"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Dokumente/emul-gs232-main/emul-gs232.py", line 177, in <module>
    resolver_module = __import__(resolver_config['module'])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resolver'
```

I tried to add to `test.yaml` in resolver section:

```yaml
     resolver:
      module: '.resolvers.stubresolver'
      class: 'StubResolver'
      config: 'stubrotor'
```

But I get:

```
resolver_module = __import__(resolver_config['module'])
    ValueError: Empty module name
```

The main code that is located in `/home/pi/Dokumente/emul-gs232-main/emul-gs232.py` looks like this:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3

  import argparse
  import serial
  import sys
  import yaml
  import resolvers
  import positioners

  '''
  emul-gs232.py 

  Each one of these functions is passed a list of arguments, with element 0 a list containing
  the positioner and resolver objects

  The list of objects and variables was chosen because these functions get called from a 
  dictionary
  object with its key the command coming in on the serial port

  Required class functions for positioner:
  stop()
  az_stop()
  el_stop()
  move_ccw()
  move_cw()
  move_up()
  move_down()
  set_position()

  Required class functions for resolver:
  get_el()
  get_az()


  '''

 def return_azel_position(args):
      ret = 'AZ=' + str(int(args[0][1].get_az())).zfill(3) + 'EL=' + str(int(args[0] 
      [1].get_el())).zfill(3)
      return ret + '\r'

 def stop_motion_all(args):
      args[0][0].stop()
      return '\r'

def stop_motion_azimuth(args):
      args[0][0].az_stop()
      return '\r'

def return_elevation(args):
      return 'EL=' + str(int(args[0][1].get_el())).zfill(3) + '\r'

def return_azimuth(args):
      return 'AZ=' + str(int(args[0][1].get_az())).zfill(3) + '\r'

def move_ccw(args):
      args[0][0].move_ccw()
      return '\r'

def move_cw(args):
     args[0][0].move_cw()
     return '\r'

def move_up(args):
     args[0][0].move_up()
     return '\r'

def move_down(args):
    args[0][0].move_down()
    return '\r'

def move_to_position(args):
    args[0][0].set_position(args[1][0],args[1][1])
    return '\r'

def move_single_axis(args):
    return '\r'

def set_speed_high(args):
    return '\r'

'''def parse_yaml(f):
     with open(f,'r') as yamlfile:
         try:
           return yaml.load(yamlfile)
         except:
           print("Can't open {0}".format(args['config']))
           sys.exit(1)'''
def parse_yaml(f):
   try:
     with open(f, 'r') as yamlfile:
        return yaml.load(yamlfile, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
   except Exception as e:
     print(f"Can't open {f}: {e}")
     sys.exit(1)
'''
A dictionary containing the function to be called is assembled here, with the key of the dict 
being the command coming in on the wire.
'''
def process_request(command,sp,positioner,resolver,debug = False):
  handlers = []
  cmd = {
        "C2":return_azel_position,
        "S":stop_motion_all,
        "B":return_elevation,
        "E":stop_motion_azimuth,
        "D":move_ccw,
        "U":move_cw,
        "W":move_to_position,
        "X1":move_single_axis,
        "L":move_down,
        "R":move_up,
        "X4":set_speed_high
      }
  handlers.append(positioner)
  handlers.append(resolver)
  if debug:
        print(f"main::process_request:Handling input command {command}")
  args = []
  args.append(handlers)
  if command in cmd:
      func = cmd[command]
      ret = func(args)
      if len(ret) > 0:
        sp.write(ret.encode())
  else:
      func = cmd[command[0]]
      a = command[1:].split()
      args.append(a)
      ret = func(args)
      if len(ret) > 0:
        sp.write(ret.encode())

        

def open_serial(port_cfg):
    sp = serial.Serial(port_cfg['device'],port_cfg['baud'],timeout=1)
    try:
        sp.is_open
    except serial.SerialException:
        print("Can't read %s" % port_cfg['device'])
        sys.exit(1)
    return(sp)

def serial_handler(sp,positioner,resolver,debug=False):
   ''' reads serial port '''
  buffer = ""
  while True:
    line = ""
    try:
        ch = sp.read()
        if ch != b'\r':
            if len(ch.decode('utf-8')) > 0:
                buffer = buffer + ch.decode('utf-8')
        else:
            if debug:
                print(f"main::serial_handler: {buffer}")
            process_request(buffer,sp,positioner,resolver,debug)

            buffer = ""
        #.decode('utf-8')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"serial_handler exception {e}")
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='gs-232B Python Emulator')
    parser.add_argument("-c","--config", required=True,
       help="YAML Config")
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug", required=False, default=False, action='store_true',
       help="Debug Logging")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    yaml_config = parse_yaml(args.config)

    ''' this loads up a resolver object ... it is rquired to pass to the positioner '''
    resolver_config = yaml_config['resolver']
    resolver_module = __import__(resolver_config['module'])
    resolver_class = getattr(resolver_module, resolver_config['class'])
    resolver = resolver_class(yaml_config[resolver_config['config']],args.debug)

    ''' load up a positioner, pass it the above resolver '''
    positioner_config = yaml_config['positioner']
    positioner_module = __import__(positioner_config['module'])
    positioner_class = getattr(positioner_module, positioner_config['class'])
    positioner =positioner_class(yaml_config[positioner_config['config']],resolver,args.debug)

    ''' open serial port configred in yaml file, begin reading the port for driver commands 
    '''
    sp = open_serial(yaml_config['serial'])
    serial_handler(sp,positioner,resolver,args.debug)
```

The YAML file is located in: `home/pi/Dokumente/emul-gs232-main/config/test.yaml`

The code:

```
 # this is the serial config for the tracker program
 # in this case, it is MacDoppler
 serial:
  device: '/dev/pts/1' #'/dev/ttyUSB1'
  baud: 9600 #57600

#
# REQUIRED resolver module
#
resolver:
 module: 'stubresolver'
 class: 'StubResolver'
 config: 'stubrotor'

# 
# REQUIRED positioner module
#
positioner:
 module: 'stubpositioner'
 class: 'StubPositioner'
 config: 'stubrotor'

stubrotor:
  up: '/dev/shm/up'
  down: '/dev/shm/down'
  cw: '/dev/shm/cw'
  ccw: '/dev/shm/ccw'
  el_out: '/dev/shm/el'
  az_out: '/dev/shm/az'
  el_timeout: 90
  az_timeout: 90
  thread_sleep: 0.66
  az_v_multiplier: .01
  el_v_multiplier: .01
  az_v_correction: 2
  el_v_correction: 2 
  az_max: 450
  el_max: 180
  relays:
   up: 'RELAY1'
   down: 'RELAY2'
   cw: 'RELAY3'
   ccw: 'RELAY4'
```

Comment: Try `module: 'resolvers.stubresolver'` without the leading period.

Comment: @9769953 It worked!!! I can't understand why. I read in some other post that for the path should be with a "." at the begining. Is that old code?